# Какая разница между $(form).submit() и $(form).ajaxSubmit() и разница между success внутри submitHandler() и success внутри submit()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation

При использовании плагина jquery.validate() возник вопрос по методу submitHandler(), внутри которого может быть  метод $(form).submit() и $(form).ajaxSubmit(). Объясните,пожалуйста, предназначение этих методов и разницу между ними. Ясно, что они отправляют форму, но зачем их вызывать, если submitHandler() итак подразумевает отправку формы. И еще какая разница в колбеках success внутри submitHandler() и success внутри submit()?

Comment: Что об этом говорит документация?

Answer (score 0):

https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#toptions

> **submitHandler** (default: native form submit)
>
> Type: Function()
>
> Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets the form as the only argument. Replaces the default submit. The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated
>
> **submitHandler** (default: native form submit)
>   функция обратного вызова для обработки актуальной отправки формы, заменяет стандартную отправку формы. Получает форму как единственный элемент. Правильное место для отправки формы через ajax после проверки.

Пример: Отправка формы через ajax

```
$("#myform").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit(); // или через form.submit();
  }
});
```

*$(form).submit() и $(form).ajaxSubmit(). Объясните,пожалуйста, предназначение этих методов и разницу между ними...*

[**.submit()**](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) - функция jquery для синхронной отправки формы, как например если бы Вы просто нажали кнопку в форме `button type="submit"` или *enter* в форме и т.п.

**.ajaxSubmit()** - не является функцией jquery, предназначается для асинхронной отправки формы (через ajax)

Иными словами, в *submitHandler* вы можете делать все, что угодно перед отправкой формы, после чего вызвать ее отправку.

Comment: И еще какая разница в колбеках success внутри submitHandler() и success внутри submit()?

Comment: @ArturHan приведите пример success внутри обоих функций. не видя кода можно лишь предположить, что разница в том, что *success* в `submitHandler` вызывается тогда, когда успешно возвращается форма, а внутри `submit()` - при успешной отправке формы (не путать с методом *success* в `validate()`).

Comment: Как может форма возвращаться, если она отправляется?

Comment: @ArturHan как и написано выше для качественного ответа на вопрос из комментария приведите пример кода. ***submitHandler** получает форму как единственный элемент...*, следовательно и *success* предположительно(!) будет вызываться в момент успешного получения формы.